# cx-Oracle missing expression when trying to copy database content with pandas and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

It should be the most simple thing in the world. However, I can't make it work.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

query = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = DATE :date_param"""

eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('conn-string', arraysize=1000)


pd.read_sql(query, eng, params={'date_param': '2022-01-01'})
```

**DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00936: missing expression**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

query = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = :date_param"""

eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine('conn-string', arraysize=1000)


pd.read_sql(query, eng, params={'date_param': datetime.date(2022, 2, 1)})
```